# Is is possible to rollback a review?

Tags: support, review

I reviewed a post and I made a mistake I clicked the **No action need** button instead of the **Skip** button.

Is it possibke to revoke my review?

Comment: Well... if you didn't do anything, what is there to rollback? If you can find the question outside of the queue just make the changes you want.

Comment: @Lix Presumably kameny is concerned that clicking "No action needed" will have led to the question exiting (or being more likely to exit) the queue. And while kameny may not have the specific knowledge to fix or judge the post they want it kept within the queue for someone else to look at